# Using progress bar to show how much account space is left

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use a progress bar to show how much of my income account is left.

E.g , i have a limit of say 1000$ stored in my account named as `limit`. Now i want to set the progress bar so that it will show how much of this amount is left. Lets say i have used 200$ and now remaining is 800$. How can i show that in progress bar.

I have tried to use `progressbar.setposition` but can't find a way to achieve above thing.

Best Regards

Comment: `progressBar.setProgress(1000-YourCurrentValueInint);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below line::

```
progressBar.setProgress(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the total value, then set the current progress:

```
progressBar.setMax(myTotalAmount)
progressBar.setProgress(myConsumedAmount)
```